# PHP memory mamagement - Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: php, mysql

I am a novice PHP developer and in the process of learning this great language. I now end up having a script consisting of 1,343,579 lines and when I try to run this I am getting the following:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 269221888) (tried to allocate 536870912 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

I have a same piece of code being repeated 512 times because I am allowing 2^9 different combinations accounting for different Search Options. I am trying my best to minimise memory leak by using `unset()`, nulling variables and sometimes explicitly calling the `gc_collect_cycles()`.

Would you please let me know whether 1 million line code will simply end up having this memory problem OR I am doing something silly in relation to memory management.

Comment: You have to consider GC of server

Comment: I'm afraid that if you ended up with 1.3 million lines of code - something is very wrong with the design of your application, it's hard to pinpoint what exactly wastes the memory. Use xdebug to see where you got leaks.

Comment: Lines of code does not correlate to memory usage. You *may* have memory leaks, but it's much more likely that you are simply accumulating lots and lots of values in memory.

Comment: Instead of repeating the code 512 times, can't you write it once as a function and use parameters to specify the search options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up your source into smaller parts and include only what you really need. When you repeat the same thing over and over again, refactor this into a separate function and call it with appropriate parameters.

Without knowing the concrete task, we cannot give more advice.

You can build your query string gradually depending on your conditions

```
function execute_query($pdo, $cond1, $cond2, $cond3, ..., $cond9)
{
    $params = array();
    $bind_types = '';
    $sql = 'select * from mytable where';

    $sql = "$sql condition1 = ?";
    $params[] = $cond1;

    if (isset($cond2)) {
        $sql = "$sql and condition2 = ?";
        $params[] = $cond2;
    }

    if (isset($cond3)) {
        $sql = "$sql and condition3 = ?";
        $params[] = $cond3;
    }

    ...

    $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    return $sth->execute($params);
}
```

Comment: thanks gentlemen. I am trying to have 9 Search options to narrow down the search. Depending on what Option a user chooses, I will then execute mysql SELECT * WHERE condition1=yes, ..., condition9=met. This is why I am repeating the code for 2^9 times. I am not familiar with MVC - does this design will lead to a shoter code?

Comment: @Siv4PHP ... and as Olaf Dietsche shows, you do not need to have separate code and queries to handle conditional conditions. You just need to use parameters and conditional statements to build your query, this is the power of coding -- it should do the work for you.

Comment: hello Olaf Dietsche, thanks for the answers. I have only 3 questions. i) do we need to use any string contanation mechanism in $sql .= "$sql and condition2 = ?"; ii) why you are using '?' in $sql? does it mean you rae using transaction approach OR just for explanation

Comment: @Siv4PHP i) Yes, you can do it either way `$sql .= ' and condition2 = ?` or `$sql = "$sql and ..."` ii) The `?` is a placeholder for prepared statements. See [PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). You can of course use the arguments directly in your SQL statement, but then you must escape them. Otherwise you're vulnerable to SQL injection. So, the recommended way nowadays is to use prepared SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak isn't normal, and shouldn't happen. You can try some solution to dismember this code on small parts and do its structured.

You can try some MVC solution like ZEND, or something.
Make sure your code doesn't doing nothing more then you need.
Review all.

Gl on that.

Comment: thanks Guerra, I am trying to have 9 Search options to narrow down the search. Depending on what Option a user chooses, I will then execute mysql SELECT * WHERE condition1=yes, ..., condition9=met. This is why I am repeating the code for 2^9 times. I am not familiar with MVC - does this design will lead to a shoter code?